# how to reduce for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, math

I have such a function:

> A(x,y,z,t)=A(x,y,z,t-1)+A(x,y,z-1,t)+A(x,y,z+1,t-1)

y,z and t are my data vectors but I had to implement the function on a grid with four for loops in Matlab and it is horrible slow. I couldn't vectorize it because of consecutiveness.Could you please advise me something?

Comment: Could you please provide a working extract of your code? Because as it is now, the order of evaluation (in the `z` direction) is very important.

Comment: please also state your version of matlab. In recent `for-loop` is actually quite fast. But it also depends what tools you will have at hand.

Comment: How is should work at `z==1`, `t==1`?

Comment: @yuk I assumed for example for index zz=2:n and in function as value z=zz-1, something like that:'A(x,y,zz,tt)=(z-1).*A(x,y,zz,tt-1)+A(x,y,zz-1,tt)+A(x,y,zz+1,tt-1)' And it helped me to avoid from index trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in your example, the following code would accomplish what you want without any for loops:

```
A = circshift(A,[0,0,0,-1]) + circshift(A,[0,0,-1,0]) + circshift(A,[0,0,1,-1])
```

This will work if you want circular shifting.  Otherwise, I think you'll have to pad with zeros and then remove the padding afterwords.